# Split larger textfile to sentences

Tags: python, regex, file, dictionary, split

I have a textfile which contains the following lines and I want to split them into lists of each sentence, one sentence is 1-5, another 1-8, and so on and there is whitespace between each sentence. For instance, one sentence list should be ['Den', 'allmänna','pensionen', 'är', 'av'], that is 1-5

```
from collections import defaultdict

out = defaultdict(list)              # Initialize dictionary for output
key = 0                              # Initialize key  

for idx, word, _ in container:       # Unpack sublists
    if int(idx) == 1:                # Check if we are at start of new sentence
        key += 1                     # Increment key for new sentence
    out[key].append(word)            # Add word to list
```

[How to slice numbered lists into sublists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20826436/how-to-slice-numbered-lists-into-sublists/20828738?noredirect=1#20828738)

The code works well but when I attempt to apply it on splitted lines directly from the testfile I get
ValueError that there are too many values to unpack. The file contains a total of 87 lines. I'd like to use the code above but not sure how to solve the ValueError.

```
1   Den     DT  DT  UTR|SIN|DEF 3   DT  _   _   _   _   P108_1:1
2   allmänna        JJ  JJ  POS|UTR/NEU|SIN|DEF|NOM 3   AT  _   _   _   _   P108_1:2
3   pensionen       NN  NN  UTR|SIN|DEF|NOM 4   SS  _   _   _   _   P108_1:3
4   är      VB  VB  PRS|AKT 0   ROOT    _   _   _   _   P108_1:4
5   av      PP  PP      4   SP  _   _


1   Folkpensionen       NN  NN  UTR|SIN|DEF|NOM 2   OO  _   _   _   _   P108_2:1
2   får     VB  VB  PRS|AKT 0   ROOT    _   _   _   _   P108_2:2
3   man     PN  PN  UTR|SIN|IND|SUB 2   SS  _   _   _   _   P108_2:3
4   oberoende       PC  PC  PRS|UTR/NEU|SIN/PLU|IND/DEF|NOM 2   AA  _   _   _   _   P108_2:4
5   av      PP  PP      4   HD  _   _   
6   tidigare        JJ  JJ  KOM|UTR/NEU|SIN/PLU|IND/DEF|NOM 7   DT  _   _   _   _   P108_2:6
7   arbetsinkomst       NN  NN  UTR|SIN|IND|NOM 4   PA  _   _   _   _   P108_2:7
8   .       MAD MAD     2   IP  _   _
```

Comment: Which line are you experiencing ValueError? It usually means the value you have on the right hand side have more values then the variables you provide on the left side. For example: `a, b = (1, 2, 3)` will throw this error. Check your input to see which line you are having problem.

Answer (score 3):

Use `itertools.groupby` and group the items using `str.isspace`:

```
from itertools import groupby

with open('abc1') as f:
    for k, g in groupby(f, str.isspace):
        if not k:
            sentence = [x.split(None, 2)[1] for x in g]
            print sentence
```

**Output:**

```
['Den', 'allm\xc3\xa4nna', 'pensionen', '\xc3\xa4r', 'av']
['Folkpensionen', 'f\xc3\xa5r', 'man', 'oberoende', 'av', 'tidigare', 'arbetsinkomst', '.']
```